# How to create dates from given date to today for every year in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

Here for example give date is 07/04/1992 and today's date is 11/20/2016.

I want output table should be

```
07/04/1992
07/04/1993
07/04/1994
07/04/1995
07/04/1996
.
.
.
.
07/04/2016
```

Please help me to get this in SAS.

Comment: Hint:  `data`, `do`.

Comment: Show your effort, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried Like this but dint work,


data dob;
input dob mmddyy10.;
datalines;
04/07/1992
;
run;


data t1;
set dob;
b=today();
dif = intck('year',dob,b);
 array diffd[dif] ; 
do i=1 to &dif.; 
 year(&i.)=intnx('year',dob,&i.,'same'); 
run;

but dint work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with dates is to treat them as such and use the date functions. This version avoids the pitfall of leap years, but (for simplicity) does not address people born February 29.

```
data want;
    format birth_date mmddyy.;

    dob = mdy(4,7,1992);
    birth_day   = day(dob);
    birth_month = month(dob);
    birth_year  = year(dob);

    end_year = year(today());
    if month(today()) <= month(dob) & day(today()) < day(dob) then
        end_year = end_year - 1;

    do year = birth_year to end_year;
        birth_date = mdy(birth_month,birth_day,year);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `DO` loop around an `OUTPUT` statement.

Let's assume you have an input dataset with the variable DOB and you want to make new variable `DATE` and generate one observation for every day from DOB to now.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  do date = dob to today();
    output;
  end;
  format date date9.;
run;
```

If you want to increment by YEAR, or any other interval, then use an index variable and the `INTNX()` function.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  do i=0 by 1 until( intnx('year',dob,i+1) > today());
    date = intnx('year',dob,i);
    output;
  end;
  format date date9.;
  drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. But this will give all the dates from dob to today,
any way to filter only for specific date in the year?

here, table should have only
04/07/1992
04/07/1993
04/07/1993
.
.
.
04/07/2016

Comment: Use the INTNX() function to generate the date. do I=0 by 1 until( intnx('year',dob,I+1)>today()); date=intnx('year',dob,I);output;end;

Answer (score 0):

If you try INTNX and SAMEDAY like in this example:

```
data have;
   infile cards;
   format date1 ddmmyy10.;
   input date1 ddmmyy10.;
   cards;
07/04/2016
;
run;

data _null_;
format date2 ddmmyy10.;
set have;
 date2=intnx('year',date1,-1,"sameday");
 put date2;
run;
```

look at the result in the log.
You can then loop changing "-1" to "-2" ... and so on.

Hope this help!